# Set the order that the browser downloads the images in

Tags: browser, lazy-loading, imagedownload

Is it possible to set the order in which images are downloaded by the browser ? Ive got about 20 images on a page and looking the network tab in developer tools in chrome they seems to be downloaded in no particular order, and the order differs every time the page is loaded.

Ive looked at some lazy loading JS plugins, but these all seem to have the same core issue that they remove the image `src` and replace it later, thus forcing the browser to take images in order, but this is TERRIBLE for seo as a search engines bot will disregard an image with no `src`.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: I forget the details, but in episode 1.10 from ttlpodcast.com Ilya Grigorik said some things that may give you some insights into the download order. If I remember right, he said that chrome/browsers will take a bunch of factors (one being whether it's a mobile browser or not) into account and try to download things in an intelligent order. I think I vaguely remember him saying that http 2.0 could help .. in the future? .. maybe?

Comment: Also, are you sure those plugins are bad for SEO? This may have changed since you posted the question. Google had announced in October that they were deprecating their old guidelines for making SPAs crawlable. The new approach is to do nothing special. Google is intelligent enough to execute js and crawl SPAs, so it may be able to handle your lazy loaded image src'es. Since google holds most of the search engine market share, you may just decide to not worry about the other search engines.